# Send data/message from server to android (not using GCM / C2DM)

Tags: android

We have a system running on an Intranet. The android app is running on a PDA client. We facilitate communication using web services done in .NET.

My question, is there a way for the server to send a message to the android app to trigger an action in the PDA (kinda like receiving SMS) ?

Previously, we used sockets since the PDA was running on Windows Mobile (as mentioned we've switched now to using Android). I've read this can be done using Google Cloud Messaging, but the system cannot connect to the internet, hence, I need alternative.

We can go back to using sockets, but I'm worried the battery life would take a huge hit.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `xmpp protocol` to implement this.`asmack` is a library available for android .(smack is for java which has some issues with android). you can use this on intranet .

Comment: AMQP protocol can also be used. There is a java client library available.

Comment: thanks for the info, we decided to use MQTT and for the server side broker http://mosquitto.org/.